# (Xcode 7.3.1) Not able to connect subview controllers to view controller.swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am trying to make a card game with multiple view controllers. I have created my application in a single view application, and have been trying to use multiple view controllers. When attempting to drag the images/buttons into the view controller code, it will not accept it unless it comes from the main view controller. I have posted screenshots that show my problem

[image: Shows that the main view controller can import items to the viewcontroller.swift]

[image: The picture of my problem]

Comment: check once you given the class name in particular view controller on stroybaord

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to make separate class for for every view controller and you have to assign that class to respective view controller from `identity inspector` from `utilities`.

Check the screenshot,

[image]

So here setting view controller is class , subclass of `viewcontroller`. So, create subclass of viewcontroller, then select respective viewcontroller from interface builder and assign that class to that view controller and then open that class in `assistant editor` and you will be able to connect outlets or ibactions.